# Missing param on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I've this code:

```
    jQuery('#send-visitor-'+postId).on('click', function() {

        console.log(ratingArray); //just to be sure

        var data = {

            action: 'send_rating',
            nonce: nonce, 
            post_id: postId,
            rating: ratingArray,
            set_type: setType

        }

        console.log(data);

        //Send value to the Server
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            //console.log(response);
        });

    });
```

ratingArray exists, I'm sure and I can see it with the console.log
Then, I do console.log(data.rating) and the everything is fine.

But when I send data var with the jQuery.post, all the params are sent unless rating.

Comment: Try using setting dataType : "json" for ajax call

Comment: @shwetachinchore: You probably meant `contentType`, if anything.

Comment: Where is the value missing? On the server?

Comment: shouldn't you convert your object to json? I think you should call JSON.stringify(data) in your post request

Comment: How are you dealing with the request on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default encoding of the data being sent to the server is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. In [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the `data` option, it says:

> **data**
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. **Object must be Key/Value pairs.**

*(My emphasis)*

So that means that your `ratingArray` is probably being converted to a string to use as a value in a key/value pair when being sent to the server. You haven't said what the contents of `ratingArray` are, but unless they can be meaningfully converted to a string by the default `Array#toString`, that's probably a problem. Seprately, if the server is expecting something other than a string version of the data, it may not deserialize `rating` correctly.

You have a couple of options:

1. Turn `ratingArray` into a string yourself, in a format that your server expects to see for the `rating` parameter and turn back into an array.
2. Send the data as JSON rather than URI-encoded form parameters. **Your server code/configuration will have to be expecting that.** To do so, you'd specify `contentType: 'json'` in your call (**and** update the server code/config to handle it). The client-side part of that would look something like this:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: ajaxurl,
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     contentType: 'json',
     success: function(response) {
       // ...
     }
   });
   ```

   **Again**, there will also be server-side changes required.
3. Send the data as a single form field with the default encoding, making the value of that single field a JSON string. Then retrieve that single value in your server-side processing code, deserialize the JSON, and work with the result. This is sometimes a bit simpler than #2. The client-side part of this would look something like this:

   ```
   jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {data: JSON.stringify(data), function(response) {
       //console.log(response);
   });
   ```

   ...and then the server would get the string from the `data` POST parameter, deserialize it from JSON, and work with it.